# Android - C++ for loop parallelized with OpenMP (with reduction) called from a Java thread causes seg fault

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk, openmp

Consider the following OpenMP-parallelized for loop:

```
void testopenmp()
{    
    int     an_int = 0;
    float   a_float = 0.0f;    
    const int num_iter = 1000;    
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(+ : an_int, a_float)
    for (int i = 0; i < num_iter; i++)
    {
        an_int++;
        a_float += (float)3.1415f;
    }
    LOG_INFO("an_int %d   a_float %f", an_int, a_float %d);
}
```

As you can see, this routine does not do anything useful. It is just a test of OpenMP reduction in a parallelized `for` loop. Consider the following activity:

```
package com.testopenmp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Thread  worker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        worker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (true)
                {
                    try {

                        testopenmp();
                        Thread.sleep(100);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return ;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        worker.start();

    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        worker.interrupt();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public static native void testopenmp();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }
}
```

The crash happens when the following steps are executed on the emulator (Api 29, x86 or x86_64 abi):

1. run the app
2. press the back button
3. run the app again

The step 3. (often) produces a segmentation fault. Sometimes i need to close and open multiple times to make it crash. At the moment of the crash the call stack is the following:

```
art_sigsegv_fault 0x00007817c0f96a40
art::FaultManager::HandleFault(int, siginfo*, void*) 0x00007817c0f96f15
___lldb_unnamed_symbol25$$app_process64 0x00005ebbee282ee8
___lldb_unnamed_symbol1$$libc.so 0x0000781842514240
__kmp_acquire_ticket_lock 0x000078176a6b3435
__kmp_enter_critical_section_reduce_block(ident*, int, int (*) [8]) 0x000078176a66feb1
__kmpc_reduce_nowait 0x000078176a66fbde
::.omp_outlined._debug__(int &, const int &, float &) native.cpp:17
::.omp_outlined.() native.cpp:18
__kmp_invoke_microtask 0x000078176a6bed93
__kmp_invoke_task_func 0x000078176a67bd1f
__kmp_launch_thread 0x000078176a67b08b
__kmp_launch_worker(void*) 0x000078176a6b9e15
__pthread_start(void*) 0x0000781842580fcf
__start_thread 0x0000781842518fe8
```

Without using the OpenMP pragma the app doesn't crash. [This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zF0btBf7HoGaP9PUy_FFWTGNXhqXphQ_) is the link to the Android Studio project, so you can try it on the fly. I would like to understand why the function `testopenmp()` causes a segmentation fault when the app is closed and run again.

Comment: Do you understand that you are _invoking_ `testopenmp()` in two threads, simultaneously, at the moment you enter the `Activity` the second time?

Comment: @greeble31 The thread is interrupted in `onDestroy()`. I have tried to use a variable to signal the thread to exit from the `run()` method. I have tried to create and close it in `onPause()` and `onResume()` but the segmentation is always there.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. Still, I'd feel better if there were a `join()` in there somewhere. I gather that `testopenmp()` is very short, < 1ms, so it does seem unlikely that two runs would coincide directly. At the same time, I'm having a hard time believing that a routine like this could exhibit different behavior by changing it from one thread to another.

Comment: @greeble31 How could two run coincide? The function `testopenmp()` is called only by the worker thread.

Comment: As I said, it seems unlikely. I'm merely being pedantic, and pointing out that you did not _guarantee_ the first worker thread terminated before you started the second one.

Comment: @greeble31 why should be a problem to invoke testopenmp() in two threads and simultaneously? that function is re-entrant.

Comment: @AndrewBloom I don't know, but it doesn't look too re-entrant to me :)

Comment: @greeble31 there are no parameters in input or output, and all the variables have local scope. So everything boils down on how OpenMP changes the code due to the #pragma directive. I would expect, from an engineering point of view, that OpenMP mantained those properties (re-entrancy and thread safety) and wondering if does not by design or specification.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your app in different scenarios with my google pixel 2xl. 
if I set `const int num_iter = 100000000;` and I minimise reopen the app multiple times (around 4 times) I get a crash `2019-12-11 12:22:29.891 8213-8636/com.testopenmp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x158 in tid 8636 (Thread-13), pid 8213 (com.testopenmp)`
Logging before and after the parallelised section shows that the multiple threads are executing the parallel section at the same time.

Another way of getting the same crash is to isolate the Runnable r and change the mainActivity code with:

```
for (int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
    worker = new Thread(r);
    worker.start();
}
```

with 9 or more threads I get the same type of crash as before, with a null pointer access on the stacktrace. `2019-12-11 12:22:30.571 8654-8654/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x158
2019-12-11 12:22:30.571 8654-8654/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference`

I don't know if this is a bug of OpenMP implementation or there's a hard limit on the number of parallel OpenMP sections that can be executed at the same time, on the other end OpenMP is designed to exploit parallelism, so you want probably only one OpenMP section executed at one given time, so that OpenMP exploits the CPU threads as best as possible. Adding another OpenMP section executed at the same time would only make the performance worse.